# How to use xml file as a parameter input for script

Tags: xml, powershell, powershell-3.0

I have a PowerShell script that must take an xml file as the input source for all the parameters/variables that will be used in the script.

How I have the param xml input code currently:

```
param([xml] $xmlData)
```

But when the script is executed I get this error:

```
PS> .\script.ps1 -xmlData .\xmlfile.xml
script.ps1 : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'xmlData'. Cannot convert
value ".\xmlfile.xml" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "The specified node cannot be inserted as the valid child of this node, because the specified node is the wrong type."
At line:1 char:22
+ .\script.ps1 -xmlData .\xmlfile.xml
+                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [script.ps1], ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,script.ps1
```

In a PS session if I do this it works fine and I can see the nodes and data parsed from the xml file, so I'm not sure how this should be done correctly or if I'm missing something:

```
PS> $xml = [xml] (gc xmlfile.xml)

PS> $xml.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    XmlDocument                              System.Xml.XmlNode
```

As a last note, my xml file does contain the xml version tag  and the structure is simple:

```
<root>
<value1>...
<value2>...
   <subnode>...
   <subvalue1>...
```

I'm skipping the closing tags and everything.

Answer (score 5):

From your description, it sounds like you need to be calling your script like this:

```
.\script.ps1 -xmlData [xml](get-content .\xmlfile.xml)
```

It's expepcting an XML object as input, not a file path, so you need to do that transform before it's passed to the script.

Comment: For me it worked in the following way-
.\script.ps1 -xmlData ([xml](get-content .\xmlfile.xml))

Answer (score 1):

Your script is expecting an XML *object* as the argument of the `xmlData` parameter.  However, you are giving it the *path* to  the XML file instead.

You need to call the script like this:

```
PS> .\script.ps1 -xmlData [xml](Get-Content .\xmlfile.xml)
```

In the above code, `(Get-Content .\xmlfile.xml)` gets the text in `.\xmlfile.xml`.  `[xml]` then converts that text into an XML object, which is exactly what your script is expecting.